# Is the Reflect capable of loading external classes/jars as plugins

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I’m searching for a proper solution for the following problem.
I developed an application that perform some operations in a common way. Now I want to make possible for this application to modify the standard behavior to something more specific depending on external classes or jar files (that may or may not be actually installed) employing common interface. These external files in assumption will be upgraded much more frequently than the main application and that’s the main reason I want them to persist separated.
What's the right approach for this task? Does the reflect is capable of this?
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you simply distribute your app as two JARs and update one more frequently? I don't see the requirement to reload that JAR during runtime.

Comment: I will provide more specifics on what I need. Application holds entities basing on XML file. Each entity is processed in a default manner. This default behavior though can be overwritten by the external class. The count of external code files is unlimited and each one of these code file can modify the behavior for its own. The name of external code file is dynamic and retrieved from cfg file. I would not like to load all external jar files at once on startup but only when it is truly required by the entity. If the external code is not there the default code in main application should be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the jar to your classPath you are able to load it, giving the effect of plugins.

But once you have loaded it into the classLoader you cannot simply refresh the class definition (in case you need to update it on the fly).

If you need an update on the fly there are some solutions like OSGi. If you can restart it every time you update the plugins you could use some simple IoC container like Spring, Guice or Tapestry IoC.

There is an interesting post [here](http://jfpoilpret.blogspot.de/2008/07/dynamically-loading-guice-modules-as.html) that may interest you, in this case the modules to be loaded are discovered on startup and loaded loading the plugins that are on the class path (each one could be a jar).

Comment: Thanks. this article looks interesting but is there any alternative for classpath modification? I assume it has to be done outside the application, right

Comment: here you can find how to set classpath: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: it's quite inconvenient to modify the path on each host running this application. Is there a way to do it internally from the Java application? Otherwise I can think of application startup scripts only.

Answer (score 0):

What Spaeth says.  However, if you need to replace classes without restarting the application you could use Commons JCI's [ReloadingClassloader](http://commons.apache.org/jci/apidocs/org/apache/commons/jci/ReloadingClassLoader.html).

Comment: If he gets serious about the plugin business, the way to go is OSGi.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I agree, but depending on his use case he might just get away with reloadingclassloader which imo has a lower impact on his app.